# Safe to delete parent of vector of pointers when those pointers have been shared?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, bnfc

I'm getting memory leak issues in one of my applications that I'm going through and trying to fix. One of my suspected problem points is where I parse lines from a file into commands using BNFC:

```cpp
void LineStreamScriptProvider::populateQueue()
{
    if(shouldPopulate())
    {
        TasScript::ShowAbsyn shower;
        std::string line;
        while(queueSize() < 30 && !stream.eof())
        {
            std::getline(stream, line);
            const char* lineCStr = line.c_str();
            TasScript::Program* lineCmds = TasScript::pProgram(lineCStr);
            TasScript::P* asLeaf = static_cast<TasScript::P*>(lineCmds);
            TasScript::ListCommand* cList = asLeaf->listcommand_;
            for_each(cList->begin(), cList->end(), [this, shower](TasScript::Command* cmd) {
                // log_to_sd_out("Parsed command %s\n", shower->show(cmd));
                std::shared_ptr<TasScript::Command> cmdShared(cmd);
                pushToQueue(cmdShared);
            });
        }
        if(stream.eof())
        {
            afterEOF();
        }
    }
}
```

For reference:

```cpp
class P : public Program
{
public:
  ListCommand *listcommand_;
// ...
```

```cpp
class ListCommand : public Visitable, public std::vector<Command*>
{
// ...
```

BNFC constructs these with `new` and then returns the pointers. Is it safe to `delete lineCmds` without deleting the value held by `cmdShared`?

Comment: Rather than creating a shared pointer from a raw pointer, why don't you create a shared pointer in the first place? That's the whole pointer of smart pointers: manage the lifetime of your objects. Plus you get exception safety with smart pointers, i.e. they will delete the memory for you if an exception is thrown on creation of an object.

Comment: > BNFC constructs these with `new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I wasn't aware of BNFC and that it creates raw pointers for you.

> Is it safe to delete lineCmds without deleting the value held by
>   cmdShared?

If you are creating a shared pointer from a raw pointer the shared pointer takes ownership of that resource. The shared pointer will maintain a reference count for that resource until it drops to zero, i.e. when all shared pointers for that resource go out of scope, at which point it will try to destroy the resource.

Here you are creating a shared pointer and passing it to a queue:

```
std::shared_ptr<TasScript::Command> cmdShared(cmd);
pushToQueue(cmdShared);
```

The shared pointer will take care of the memory management for you. So there is no need to explicitly call `delete` on the vector of commands. Once all shared pointers of type `std::shared_ptr<TasScript::Command>` are destroyed the resource is also destroyed.

So no, it is not safe to delete a vector of pointers in this case.

---

Another simpler solution is to take a copy of the `TasScript::Command`:

```
TasScript::Command cmdCopy(*cmd);
```

Then change `pushToQueue()` to accept by `const TasScript::Command&`, not by shared pointer. Then you don't have to worry about the pointer being destroyed since you have a copy of the value.

It looks like in your while loop you are leaking memory. Don't you have to delete `lineCmds` and `cList`?

Comment: So like this? https://mystb.in/evegezufor.cpp `pushToQueue` needs to take a `shared_ptr` because its accessed in weird ways across threads.

Comment: Or would something like https://mystb.in/qakizetaka.cpp be more correct?

Comment: @Soren Is `ListCommand` a class you have created? If so, can't you change it to `class ListCommand : public Visitable, public std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Command>>`? Then you can work on a vector of shared pointers. That will be a better design and easier to work with in the code. Then you don't need to create a shared pointer in the `for_each`.

Comment: @Soren Maybe you can take a copy of the command after all. That way you can destroy the pointers and don't worry about any invalidated pointer after the loop. See my second solution.